# Wordpress Post HTML after Posting

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, php

I am writing a plugin for WordPress, one of the tasks I need to-do is send the HTML content of a new post to an e-mail address at the time of posting, I know I can use certain hooks to fire after the post has been saved, but is there a way to get the full HTML content of the new page/post with the theme applied?

I have custom fields within the post so ideally I would like to get the whole post from the URL rather then reconstructing all the fields to then send in HTML.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Is this the kind of thing your looking for: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut156.shtml

Comment: Are you trying to send an HTML e-mail or are you trying to send the post as an attachment (in the HTML format) because if its the former; you might have a hard time getting your HTML to display correctly in the destination e-mail client because HTML in e-mails is not as robust as that of todays browser clients obviously. Depending on what you are tyring to do exactly I'd probably look at writing a function to hook into the save_posts that uses PHPs DOM Parser [HERE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: I am basically wanting to send the captured HTML post to a mailing list which is handled by MailChimp, I have managed to get all the API working, I literally just need a copy of the blog post in HTML so I can send an HTML email to the list each time a new post is made.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('publish_post', 'email_post');
function email_post($postID)
{
    $post = get_post($postID);
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
    $mailto = 'youremail';
    $subject = 'New Post';
    if(mail($mailto, $subject, $content))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Be sure to set your headers or anything else you might need to populate your email correctly. This is untested, but it should help get you started. Also consider using the 'save_post' hook.

I've posted this same reply on StackOverflow, so if this helps, please mark both of these as answered.

Answer (score 0):

See the save_post action hook - http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: Yes, I am using that hook, but how can I get access to the HTML of the article posted?